# Analogue to <e4view> for command handlers

Tags: eclipse-plugin, e4

I am writing a plugin for the Eclipse IDE and have registered (in my `plugin.xml`) an E4 part using the `<e4view>` element of the `rg.eclipse.ui.views` extension point. However, I fail to see how I can register an E4 command handler (`@Execute` method rather than `AbstractHandler` base class) in a similar fashion.

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: As far as I know, no it isn't possible.

Comment: OK, I guess I can register my handler in the `fragment.e4xmi` then. However, how do I then create a popup menu for my view with the handler as a direct command? After all, the part is in the application model (as far as my `e4xmi` is concerned).

Comment: In e4 the popup menu is defined in the Menus section of the Part / Part Descriptor in the e4xmi.

Comment: Thanks, @greg-449. I have indeed switched to a pure `fragment.e4xmi` now.